# How to pull with jenkins from bitbucket using certificate

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I try to pull from my bitbucket repo using certificates.
My jenkins is running in a docker container.

Now I tried to create a key with `ssh-keygen` and I placed the public key in the `bitbucket -> settings --> deployment keys`.

In my Jenkins project I defined my username of bitbucket + the private key.

At the moment my cert looks like this at the end (public cert): `root@jenkins-7xevr`.

What am I doing wrong?
Do I have to create this cert in a specific way or in a specific place?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the certificate on the Jenkins slave machine (the one where you pull the code)

Once the keys is there do a git fetch or git pull manually for the first time so that the keys will be added to your known host file.

After that you should be able to pull/push

Comment: hi, I did create the cert in my jenkins slave. what command do I have to perform to pull manually. This is what I see in bitbucket: https://username@bitbucket.org/proj/repo.git

Comment: do a `git clone` and then a `git fetch`. just once to be sure that you can pull code from the repository,

Comment: git clone (my repo) is asking for a password but I want to use my cert?

Comment: So you have clone using http/https instead of ssh

Comment: This is why i told you to test first :-) to verify that you have set git correctly